# (Ubuntu 16.04) IPv6 not working

Tags: 16.04, ipv6

I'm still new to linux/ubuntu, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to get IPv6 working. IPv4 (and my internet) works fine, but when I test for IPv6 on ipv6-test.com it says I don't have IPv6:

[image]

My windows machine (on same network) works mostly fine however:

[image]

I've tried the code:

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "Running kernel is IPv6 ready"
```

Which brings up "Running kernel is IPv6 ready"

Not sure where to go from here (still learning this). Thanks for any help.

Comment: And where is your IP address coming from exactly? Are you specifying it manually?

Comment: Oh, it's coming from router dhcp.

Comment: Does your ISP give you an IPv6 prefix? Does your router handle IPv6? What does `ip address` say, are there any inet6 addresses _not_ starting with `f`?

Comment: Yeah ISP gives prfix (2600: ...), and router does support it. Far as I can tell all my devices/machines can function over IPv6. Even my pi (running Raspbian Jessie) shows as supported on that web test, and also gets (over DHCP from router) a IPv6 address with prefix. 'ip address' lists 4 addresses (excluding loopback), one IPv4 which is correct, and three IPv6. The three IPv6 addresses all start with 'fe' and say 'scope link tentative dadfailed' after, and 'valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever' below.

Comment: Are you sure it is coming from dhcp6 rather than autoconfigured via router advertisements?  Did you configure dhcpv6 on the router?

Comment: @user4556274 It should be coming from the DHCPv6. I can turn the DHCPv6 on router off and on. When it's on, the other devices all get an IPv6 (with 2600:* prefix) within the given range. When it's off, the devices auto configure their own (with 2600:* prefix), but clearly outside the range. So it seems the router is handling DHCPv6/SLAAC properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to set up DHCP to issue v6 requests on **dhclient.conf**.

Check this out: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DHCPv6 (ISC DHCP v6 Client section).

There it suggests you can enable it by adding this line to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
send dhcp6.oro 1, 2, 7, 12, 13, 23, 24, 39;
```

If you want to dig further on DHCP client settings refer to its man page, accessible either via the **man dhclient.conf** and this link: http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf

Comment: I added 'send dhcp6.oro 1, 2, 7, 12, 13, 23, 24, 39;' to the dhclient.conf, and restarted networking/dhclient but nothing seemed to have changed. I looked at http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf and noticed it didn't have the 'From man dhclient.conf:' block of text mentioned on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DHCPv6 which seems strange.

Comment: True! It seems options on ubuntu's dhcp client with v6 support are not exactly the same in the original package. But that's amusing, they have a page to fix this specific issue with specific instructions... that don't work.

Comment: Do you have a line that reads **iface eth0 inet dhcp** in **your /etc/network/interfaces** file? if so, try adding also a **iface eth0 inet6 dhcp** line, that will be at least one of the causes it don't work.

Comment: I added that line, didn't seem to affect anything however. The file contained a comment and 2 lines, 'auto lo' & 'iface lo inet loopback'. The line is in there now though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the "wide-dhcpv6-client" to be a little friendlier than that of ISC. Once installed, make sure you update /etc/default/wide-dhcpv6-client to match your intended interface. Take a look at /etc/default/wide-dhcpv6-client as well. Here's a decent starting point for a config:

```
interface eth0
{ 
  send ia-na 1;
  send ia-pd 0;
  request domain-name-servers;
  request domain-name;
  request ntp-servers;
  script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};
```

Also, on 16.04, be careful with some of the sysctl options. There are some odd defaults that were introduced. You can show your route table with "ip -6 route". It should have a default listed (regardless of DHCP) if your router is indeed sending out RAs to the network. If not, check to make sure it's enabled with:

```
sysctl -a | grep accept_ra_defrtr
```

Your interface should not show "0" for that option if you're expecting a default route to be learned via RAs.

Dan