# IPv6 not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ipv6

After searching the web for weeks I give up and come to ask this question (again). I've  checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809853/ubuntu-16-04-ipv6-not-working) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645008/ipv6-connect-network-is-unreachable) but my problem was not solved.

So I have a Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 (dual sys) computer and an ethernet connection that I am sure has IPv6 connection. I've tried to visit IPv6 sites on Windows system and it works great. But it won't work on Ubuntu, which is frustrating.

Now when I run `ifconfig` it gives:

```
      eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:4d:7b:b8:4f:7d  
                inet addr:166.111.66.250  Bcast:166.111.67.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
                inet6 addr: fe80::10d8:ad64:c0dc:f66a/64 Scope:Link
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:26102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:1548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                RX bytes:3022053 (3.0 MB)  TX bytes:286019 (286.0 KB)
                Interrupt:16 Memory:df200000-df220000 

      is0       Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
                inet6 addr: 2402:f000:1:1501:200:5efe:a66f:42fa/64 Scope:Global
                inet6 addr: 2402:f000:1:1501:71aa:6848:6f44:8992/64 Scope:Global
                inet6 addr: 2402:f000:1:1501::/64 Scope:Global
                inet6 addr: fe80::200:5efe:a66f:42fa/64 Scope:Link
                UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1280  Metric:1
                RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:81 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
                RX bytes:288 (288.0 B)  TX bytes:6416 (6.4 KB)

      lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
                inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
                inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
                UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
                RX packets:530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
                RX bytes:74472 (74.4 KB)  TX bytes:74472 (74.4 KB)

      wlx30b49e2f621f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:b4:9e:2f:62:1f  
                UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So I believe I have an IPv6 address(fe80::10d8:ad64:c0dc:f66a). However, when I try to access an IPv6 website, I just can't get through. I have changed `/etc/network/interfaces` following some links and it looks like

```
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback
      iface eth0 inet dhcp
      iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
```

and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. It looks like

```
      [main]
      plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
      dns=dnsmasq

      [ifupdown]
      managed=true
```

Now I can run `host -t AAAA google.com` and it returns `google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4008:800::200e` but when I `ping6 2404:6800:4008:800::200e`, there is just no reply, nor can I visit any IPv6 only website.

I'm not sure if I messed something up since I remembered to use IPv6 before. Could someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did that is0 interface get there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have no idea why the `is0` interface appeared there. I haven't enabled IPv6-over-IPv4 since I already have a generic IPv6 connection. Should I disable the `is0` interface? Why did it have several IPv6 addresses while none is the same as in `eth0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have an IPv6 address on eth0. You have only a link local `fe80::10d8:ad64:c0dc:f66a/64` address that is not good to connect outside of your local network.

Remove `iface eth0 inet dhcp` and `iface eth0 inet6 dhcp` from the `/etc/network/interfaces`. Network Manager will receive an IPv6 address if it is available.

If you really have to use manual configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the correct setting for IPv6 will be

```
 iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

since in many cases DHCPv6 is not used on a router. The most common is SLAAC configuration.

Comment: That two lines (`iface eth0 inet dhcp` and `iface eth0 inet6 dhcp`) were added after IPv6 failed and removing them didn't work. By the way, do I have to restart my computer to make the changes effective? I might not be able to reboot the system for some days.

Comment: You need to restart Network Manager and probably networking service too.

Comment: I tried the two methods but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You did not give any information. I see that you have `is0` interface that has a valid IPv6 address. So it is unclear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what other information should I provide. I'm trying to access a VPS using its IPv6 address and copy big files to local machine etc, since IPv6 traffic is free and IPv4 traffic is not in my college. And currently I am not able to ping the IPv6 address. It either says `network unreachable` or just won't return anything. So to connect to my VPS using IPv6 only, I need to make the IPv6 connection working first.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. Later on I found out that I actually didn't have a generic IPv6 connection. The only way for me to use IPv6 is by [isatap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISATAP). That is, IPv6-over-IPv4.

As mentioned in my question, I do have an interface (i.e. `is0`) that achieves this functionality, yet I don't know why it didn't work. I have to manually disable `is0`, create a new interface, connect to the isatap router on my campus and everything works. Later on the `is0` interface would show up again but this time, it doesn't matter.

Anyway thank you for your advice.

Comment: Wow. ISATAP is truly ancient. It's not recommended for new IPv6 deployments and hasn't been for almost a decade. That's why it never occurred to me. I would ask when your campus IT services will deploy native IPv6 properly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well they already have deployed native IPv6 in many buildings except the one that I'm in, probably due to some "historic" authority issues. Anyway I'm good with ISATAP.