# Can't ping dynamic IPv6 Xubuntu hostname from Kubuntu laptop

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns, ipv6, hostname

Ever since I updated my computers yesterday with the latest Ubuntu updates, I have been having issues with the computers communicating with each other. Originally, nothing (Either my mobile [Android], Main Driver laptop [Kubuntu LTS], or Storage Laptop [Kubuntu LTS]) could ping my Media Centre [Xubuntu LTS]. After an hour I was able to fix the Media Centre and can ping and send data to and from it via my mobile [Android] or storage laptop [Kubuntu LTS].

However my Main Driver Laptop [Kubuntu LTS] still cannot find an IPv6 address using hostnames through mdns6 (Either my Media Centre [Xubuntu LTS] or Storage Laptop [Kubuntu LTS]). I can ping the IPv4 addresses and this works, I can ping the multiple IPv6 addresses and this works, but I cannot get an IPv6 address using the hostname with mdns6 prioritised in nsswitch.conf.

Message received when attempting to ping my Media Centre from my Main Driver laptop:

```
dave@dave-laptop:~$ ping media-centre.local
ping: media-centre.local: Name or service not known
```

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   dave-laptop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My host.conf file:

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

My nsswitch.conf file:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns6_minimal dns6 mdns_minimal dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

My avahi-daemon.conf:

```
# This file is part of avahi.
#
# avahi is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# avahi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
# or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with avahi; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

# See avahi-daemon.conf(5) for more information on this configuration
# file!

[server]
#host-name=foo
#domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
#allow-interfaces=eth0
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=yes
#disallow-other-stacks=no
#allow-point-to-point=no
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
#disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
#publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
#publish-domain=yes
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no
#reflect-filters=_airplay._tcp.local,_raop._tcp.local

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
#rlimit-core=0
#rlimit-data=8388608
#rlimit-fsize=0
#rlimit-nofile=768
#rlimit-stack=8388608
#rlimit-nproc=3
```

I have also tested switching the nsswitch.conf preference to WINS first. This works, but of course, it's IPv4. I would prefer that everything run on IPv6 and dynamic addresses. Could you please assist me?

Thanks.

Comment: This is your local network, so its private IPv4 range is nowhere near exhaustion. Is there any user-facing benefit that is the reason fro your insistence on IPv6?

Comment: Just a preference I guess. A few years ago on previous setups I was using IPv4 by default and I found that I would occasionally have timeouts when transferring large files across the local network. After that I switched to IPv6 and the issues disappeared. Also found the performance slightly more optimum when transferring files across the network, but this was a few years ago, so may have just been the software of the time. So it's more for performance and reliability reasons, not IP exhaustion reasons.

Comment: Just done some more testing and realised that this isn't an IPv6 issue. I changed nsswitch.conf to use mdns4_minimal and dns4 first, rebooted and still cannot ping. Therefore seems to be more of a mdns issue I think. But adding WINS connects it to IPV4 address.

Comment: Then again, I just ran an IPv6 test on the Main Driver laptop and it failed 0/10. Then I ran it on the storage laptop (On the exact same network) passes 10/10. This was on https://test-ipv6.com/ . But pinging an IPv6 address on the local network works fine

Comment: Just thought I'd re-check if I still could ping the media-centre's IPv6 address from the Main Driver laptop after running that IPv6 test, but this still works. So, I can't seem to isolate the problem. Might be more than one problem because it doesn't make sense: Can ping Google's IPv4 address directly, Can't ping Google's IPv6 address directly, can ping local network IPv6. Might need to focus on why IPv6 isn't working outside the local network before working on the hostname issue.

Comment: You can use `avahi-resolve -n something.local` and `avahi-discover` to isolate the problem. If those don't work, look at what packets are missing in Wireshark compared to when things are working

Comment: Thanks. I tried avahi-resolve and I received: Failed to resolve host name 'media-centre.local': Timeout reached . Avahi-discover only shows itself through Windows networking. I think I'm close to figuring out what's wrong with IPv6 though. It appears through if-config that the interface has only been assigned a "link-local" address. I compared the ifconfig results to my storage laptop and the storage laptop has IPv6 addresses assigned correctly. I learned this from another Ask Ubuntu answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896289/ipv6-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04 .

Comment: However, the old answer refers to /etc/network/interfaces which doesn't exist on either of my Kubuntu laptops. It appears the answer is too old and they've changed the networking setup on modern Ubuntu versions. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: It says: Remove iface eth0 inet dhcp and iface eth0 inet6 dhcp from the /etc/network/interfaces. Network Manager will receive an IPv6 address if it is available. This is not possible on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: You should be able to do this via the IPv6 tab in the connection GUI

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the IPv6 tab connection GUI. It has Method: Automatic, Privacy: Default, the rest blank or unticked. Identical to the storage laptop that's working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I misinterpreted the fault as being a problem with mDNS over IPv6. Instead I don't even have proper IPv6 addresses assigned to my laptop after the Ubuntu Update (Only Link Local). Because this seems to be the underlying cause of the fault, I have asked a new question on the site here: [Only IPv6 Link Local Address after Ubuntu update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504030/only-ipv6-link-local-address-after-ubuntu-update) .