# Only IPv6 Link Local Address after Ubuntu update

Tags: networking, network-manager, ip, ipv6

Since recently running a software update on my Kubuntu laptop, I only have a Link Local address assigned for IPv6. The connection GUI IPv6 configuration looks normal and identical to my working Kubuntu Storage laptop [Method: Automatic, Privacy: Default, rest is blank or unchecked].

I previously asked a question here: [Previous Ask Ubuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503895/cant-ping-dynamic-ipv6-xubuntu-hostname-from-kubuntu-laptop)

about mDNS not appearing to work over IPv6. After some fault finding with Daniel T, it appears the deeper reason for this is because IPv6 isn't even working correctly. I have tested the laptop using my Mobile Hotspot, and this still doesn't work (However, it works on my storage laptop). I also tried forcing it to connect only using IPv6 and it fails.

My ifconfig is as follows:

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:eb:f6:92:f6:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2944  bytes 236278 (236.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2944  bytes 236278 (236.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.186  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::fd80:7e58:9a5:86f2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 14:13:33:68:a9:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5525  bytes 2704633 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4747  bytes 685755 (685.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any differences in `sysctl net.ipv6` ?

Comment: Not that I can see. There are adaptor name differences, but when I go through the adaptor sections line by line, the numbers are identical line by line. The non-adaptor name parts are identical also.

Comment: Just finished backing up all of my files, formatted and installed Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Connected to the Wifi after install without updating but still only Link Local address. I then attempted to look for an older 22 LTS version, but the Kubuntu old version links are broken in such a way that they all re-direct to 22.04.4. By the looks of it I might be able to get the older Ubuntu version (Non KDE) though. I'll attempt with both the latest Ubuntu and an old version and see what happens.

Comment: I have now confirmed it. A fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS will cause my computer to only have a Link Local address for IPv6. With a fresh install of 22.04.3 LTS the fault is not present. I also just discovered that my other computers (despite running the updater at roughly the same time) are still running 22.04.3 LTS variants. Is there anything I can do to get the developers to fix this fault (Like raising a bug report) and what information will they need (eg. Commands for device info)?

Comment: Can you run `diff -u3 -r /etc /path/to/copy/of/other/etc` ?

Comment: I don't see any network-related change. Thanks for the 22.04.0{3,4} idea. I might investigate sometime but please file a bug to https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager . Please also delete the paste.ubuntu comment and change your passwords, and look over and redact the password (/etc/shadow only contains password hashes, but still). I regret not specifying "run diff and only post interesting networking-related changes"

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've now raised a Bug Report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2054864