# Cannot find my IPv6

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ipv6

I have been having networking issues, now out of the blue my IPv6 does not appear, my router is set up for IPv6 and I have looked through the logs.  I am running **Ubuntu Server 20.04**
`ip address`

```
root@sturtz001:/etc# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:08:58:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
       valid_lft 86091sec preferred_lft 86091sec
    inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:bf:e7:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
       dhcp4: yes
       dhcp6: no
       accept-ra: true
    ens2:
       dhcp4: no
       dhcp6: yes
       accept-ra: true
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu

Comment: @chili555 Here you go

Comment: Right beneath and aligned exactly with `version: 2` please add: `renderer: networkd` Then do: `sudo netplan --debug generate` followed by: `sudo netplan apply` Any improvement? It may take a reboot.

Comment: I did that @chili555 I now am rebooting

Comment: I get 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:08:58:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
       valid_lft 86250sec preferred_lft 86250sec
    inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: How is IPv6 configured? SLAAC or DHCPv6?

Comment: @vidarlo how do I find out?

Comment: Check your router configuration. Or fire up wireshark and look for Router Advertisment messages. You could also try to add a line with `accept-ra: true` beneath the `dhcp6: true` line -  at same indentation.

Comment: @vidarlo Do I have to reboot after making that change?

Comment: @NathanielSturtz you don't *have to*, but it's perhaps the easiest way to ensure it's applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112484/discussion-between-nathaniel-sturtz-and-vidarlo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted my ISP and they turned on the Ipv6 DNS
IPv6 was already on but they told me to reboot my router so I did.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your ISP provides you with IPv6? My router is also set up for IPv6 (and IPv4) but my ISP only gives IPv4. I would have to ask them to change it if I wanted IPv6.

In my router interface I can see in the status that IPv6 is dissconnected. Maybe you could look there.

**Edit:**
You could use Wireshark. I don't know how you should run it from CLI but it is possible and it should also show your IPv6 if you have any connections to or from it.

[Wireshark Docs on CLI](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html)

Also note the Ubuntu Docs on [Wireshark](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wireshark/). You need to grant at least some privileges to your user.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I am in contact with them now

Comment: you could try wireshark

Comment: What is Wireshark?

Comment: it is basicly an analysis tool for all network traffic (even bluetooth). shows you all pakages with source and destination.

Comment: Oh Ok. Thank you, I will look into it

Comment: I cannot install it.

Comment: hm weird. How exactly did you try and what was the error message?

Comment: I also just remembered hearing about some peole having issues with their server and ipv6 DS-lite. Could that be the case here? or do you have full IPv6?

Comment: What is IPv6 DS-lite?

Comment: I don't kow very much about it and I'm still not entirely sure where your problem lies. But it is a way for you to get both IPv6 and IPv4 without actually allocating an IPv4 address to you. When you then try to access your server via IPv4 you can get stuck at someone elses router, because you share the IPv4 address. So while you can reach both IPv4 and IPv6 from within DualStack-lite Network you might have problems reaching it from the outside with IPv4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism . If you have full DualStack you would have both without sharing.

Comment: I belive you have yome kind of DualStack because you claim your ISP said you have IPv6 and on the other anwser you said you got the IPv4 `199.66.15.46` back from an IP test. So clearly you somehow have both.

Comment: I have both but my server just won't find the IPv6

Comment: have you tried on another machine in the same network? and does the router acctually display an IPv6 address in the status tab?

Comment: Yes it does, and I cannot run this command on my MacBook, it is not mine, it is the Schools, I will have to do it tomorrow.

Comment: I get 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 2: enp1s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:5b:35:83:b7:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:bb:cf:1e:66:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 86364sec preferred_lft 86364sec
    inet6 fe80::9e3b:a767:78f0:166b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken, the IPv6 is shown right there:

```
inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope link
```

Comment: fe80: is a link-local address, meaning that no valid IPv6 address was received from the DHCP server.

Comment: oh, sorry. You learn new things every day.

Comment: Try this, it's harmless but useful www.testmyipv6.com

Comment: @darth_epoxy How do I find it from CLI?

Comment: When I run `wget -q -O - http://testmyipv6.com/ | grep -A1 myIPaddr | tail -n1` I get 
`199.66.15.46`

Comment: I am not aware of a command line interface for that site but of course you can `firefox testmyipv6.com` at the command line and launch your browser.

Comment: I am running a server, I don't have a GUI

Comment: @RAID Welcome!!

Comment: You might find some clues here https://askubuntu.com/questions/809853/ubuntu-16-04-ipv6-not-working